# Como simular respostas JSON?

Tags: json, mock, http-request

Preciso de algo que simule respostas JSON para mim. Há um tempo atras tinha visto um site que fazia o seguinte:

- Você passa parêmetros por uma URL, ex: `?nome=Wesley&idade=21`
- Recebia na chamada o objeto em JSON assim:

  ```
   {
       nome:"Wesley",
       idade : 21
   }
  ```

Mas não consigo encontrá-lo, o que seria algo que faz coisa semelhante?

Comment: o que você procura é o site que faz isso? ou como transformar essa query no url num objeto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você procura um serviço que você passe alguns parâmetros e ele retorno em formato `JSON`?

Acredito que seja algo similar a [esse](http://www.jsontest.com/) site.

Onde essa chamada: `http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two`

Tem esse retorno:

```js
{
   "one": "two",
   "key": "value"
}
```

Verifique se isso lhe atende. Apesar de não aceitar `QueryString`, como solicitado na pergunta.

Comment: O único pequeno inconveniente é o de o serviço não aceitar os parâmetros no formato de uma querystring como demonstrado no pelo autor do tópico. Mas isso é mínimo, já que por haver uma API basta preparar os dados antes de consumir.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, sim, até achei que seria encontrada uma no formato que o autor solicitou e fiquei de olha, para já salvar em meus favoritos, para quando necessitar. Mas por enquanto nada. hehe

Answer (score 5):

Eu uso esse site para mock de JSON.
Não é exatamente o que você pediu, mas pode ajudar:
http://www.json-generator.com/

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o que você precisa é serializar sua coleção de `QueryString`s.

Em C#, você pode criar um *handler* com o seguinte conteúdo:

```cs
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Request.QueryString);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(jsonContent);
}
```

Todo conteúdo passado para esse handler será devolvido em formato JSON, exatamente como no seu exemplo.